# Umbraco v7 Audit Trail History Information

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have done several google searches and even several searches in the Our Umbraco forum (http://our.umbraco.org/forum) and stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com) which have resulted in little to no information about the Audit Trail functionality in any version of Umbraco much less the newest version 7.

So hopefully someone can answer the following questions about Umbraco v7 Audit Trail Functionality:

1. What is the basic functionality offered in Umbraco's Audit Trail?
2. Where is the documentation describing this basic functionality?
3. Is there any default functionality around trimming or deleting these audit trails in Umbraco?
4. If so, can you turn the trimming/deleting feature off?

I have a client that wants to be able to query audit log data for all time of their website once they go live in production. My hope is that this is the default functionality of Umbraco but please help me understand how I might change this if this is not the case.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like there is not a lot of documentation around this feature; however, Jan said in his response to [my our.umbraco.org question](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/66752-audit-trail-logs-history-inforamtion]) that he didn't think it would automatically trim or delete these audit logs.  So until I hear otherwise this is going to be my assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Audit Trail logs the changes to a document. It logs the node id, the date/time, the user and the action that was performed.

From my experience the Audit Trail is not trimmed or deleted.

The Audit details are stored in the umbracoLog table in the database. Looking at the data in the table can give you better insight than through the Umbraco Backoffice if more detail is required. The Backoffice will only show the activity on a given document so it is not possible to see history across the site. The data in the table also gives you access to delete actions. It is not possible to see when something was deleted in the back office. The table only stores the node id so it does have to be joined with the other tables to get document names.

Also see Dan Diplo's [Audit Log Viewer](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/diplo-audit-log-viewer/) package.

Dallas